# Can not delete post's comment reactively in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

In my blog-like Vue.js app, the posts are rendered in a `v-for` loop. When a button under each post is clicked, its comments are fetched from the server and attributed like this, as `post` objects have no `comments` attribute:

```
  `this.$set(post, 'comments', res.data.comments) ;`
```

The code to render the comments is this:

```
<div v-for="(c, j) in post.comments" :key="j">                           
    <span>{{c.body}}</span> 
    <span v-if="post.user_id==userId" @click="delComment(c, post)">Delete me!</span>
</div>
```

And the deleteing method:

```
  delComment(c, post) {
    const payload = {
           token: this.token,
           cid: c.id
      }
    axios.delete(this.BASE_URL + "/api/comment", { data: payload } )
    .then( (res)=> {       
      post.comments = this.post.comments.filter((comment)=>{
         return comment.id != c.id
      });      
      this.$set(post, 'comments', post.comments) ;
    })
    .catch( error => {  
      console.log(error);
    });
  },
```

But when I click the Delete link, I get this error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined
    at eval (Home.vue?76f2:540)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I realized that the culprit was an extra `this` in `this.post.comments.filter((comment)`.

The working code is this:

```
delComment(c, post) {
    const payload = {
           token: this.token,
           cid: c.id
      }
    axios.delete(this.BASE_URL + "/api/comment", { data: payload } )
    .then( (res)=> {       
      post.comments = post.comments.filter((comment)=>{
         return comment.id != c.id
      });      
      this.$set(post, 'comments', post.comments) ;
    })
    .catch( error => {  
      console.log(error);
    });
  },
```

Thanks guys for sharing your thoughts!

Comment: i was assuming that `post` is data object property, sorry

Comment: Sorry guys if I was not clear enough. Appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `this` before `post` :

```
 //v-------------//here
  this.post.comments = this.post.comments.filter((comment)=>{
     return comment.id != c.id
  });
```

and here  :

```
      //----------v--------------------v
      this.$set(this.post, 'comments', this.post.comments) ;
```

Update :

i was assuming that you a property called post in your data object as follows:

```
  data(){
     return{
        post:[]
       ...
        }
   }
```

so in this case you should remove any `this` before `post` variable.

Comment: This still gives `TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined`

Comment: and what about ` this.$set(post, 'comments', post.comments) ;` you should also add this before post ?

Comment: I still get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined`

Comment: in the code that you provided i could only see these cases that cause this issue, please provide any code snippet that use `comments` property

Comment: I thinks you misunderstanding what `this` refers to here.